# Replace the character input by user

Tags: java, string

> Java program to find a character from a sentence and replace it with another character. If the character is not found in the string print "character not found".
>
> Note: Replace only the first occurrence.
>
> Sample input 1:
>
> Enter the string:
>
> java programming
>
> Enter the character to be searched:
>
> a
>
> Enter the character to replace:
>
> o
>
> Sample output 1:
>
> jova programming

Kindly suggest me how to take user input for the character to be replaced and replace the character.

Comment: *"Kindly suggest me how to take user input for the character to be replaced .."* Read it from the command line, the same way the current code is reading the string that needs to be changed. *".. and replace the character."* Look at the methods for [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) - they contain all you need.

Answer (score 2):

In general to get a input from user you could a scanner class.

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
System.out.println("Enter the character to be searched");
String characterToReplace = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input

System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
String replacementCharacter = myObj.nextLine();
```

Information on scanner class
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Other ways to read input from command line :

```
BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

For replacing a character you could just string.replace method to perform the required operations.

Comment: `userName` Please help instill good practices for newbies by using *meaningful* attribute names.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by putting this code in a function:

```
Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the string to search:");
String search = readInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the character to be searched:");
String find = readInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the character to replace it with:");
String replace = readInput.nextLine();
if (search.contains(find)) {
    return search.replaceFirst(find, replace);
} else {
    return "Character not found";
}
```

Comment: He said take input from the user. Bad answer. Read the question next time please. Also, he said he wants an error if the character isn't found; please demonstrate this by using return values of replaceFirst.

Comment: @Bob Updated answer

Comment: Much better! This addresses every single one of their points!